# Color provinces in my country with Google charts (geocharts)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to light up "Ha Noi" and "Ho Chi Minh" using Google Charts but it's not working by modifying the example in the document.

```js
      google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages':['geochart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Provinces', 'Popularity'],
          ['Hanoi', 200],
          ['HCM', 300],
        ]);

        var options = {region:'VN',resolution:'provinces'};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/na8hvgts/

I wonder whether it's possible at all to color provinces/states outside the US.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using the [ISO 3166-2:VN codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:VN)

see following working snippet...

also, the `colorAxis` will default to the min and max values in the data

leaving the min value transparent when there are only two rows

set specific `colorAxis.min` / `colorAxis.max` to avoid...

```js
      google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages':['geochart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Provinces', 'Popularity'],
          [{v: 'VN-HN', f: 'Hanoi'}, 200],
          [{v: 'VN-SG', f: 'HCM'}, 300],
        ]);

        var options = {
          region:'VN',
          resolution:'provinces',
          colorAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 400
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: This helps tremendously. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, can we change the label when I hover from 'VN-HN' to Hanoi, and 'VN-SG' to 'Ho Chi Minh' @WhiteHat

Comment: sure, i changed the answer above, use object notation to provide the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`) - the tooltip will use the formatted value